# Sbt cannot synchronize the project because it cannot be compiled

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, coursera-api

I am quite at the beginner level so I would gladly accept some help to solve this problem...

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.5 Sbt version: 1.2.6 JDK version: 1.8.0_191-b12 Scala is used as IntelliJ plugin (the most recent).

When I load the sbt project downloaded from coursera webpage with InteliJ the project is not synchronizing and I see lots of error messages. Also in build.sbt lines are red. I have copied the error messages and the lines of the build.sbt.

Here are the error messages. The list is not complete because of the max limit of links:

Error while importing sbt project:

```
;reload; set root.org.jetbrains.sbt.StructureKeys.sbtStructureOptions in 
Global := "download resolveClassifiers resolveSbtClassifiers" 
;/:dumpStructureTo C:/Users/KOMPOS~1/AppData/Local/Temp/sbt-structure2.xml; 
session clear-all [info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\Komposzt 
fâ”ĽÄąkapitâ”śĂ­ny.sbt\0.13\plugins [info] Loading project definition from 
C:\Users\Komposzt fâ”ĽÄąkapitâ”śĂ­ny\Desktop\example 1\project [info] Set 
current project to progfun1-example (in build 
file:/C:/Users/Komposzt%20f%C5%91kapit%C3%A1ny/Desktop/example%201/) [info] 
Defining /:sbtStructureOptions
[info] The new value will be used by /:ssOptions
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to progfun1-example (in build
file:/C:/Users/Komposzt%20f%C5%91kapit%C3%A1ny/Desktop/example%201/)
Downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala- 
parser-combinators_2.12/1.1.1/scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.1.1.pom.sha1 
Downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit- 
4.12.pom.sha1 
Downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.12/2.2.6/scalatest_2.12-2.2.6.pom

Downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala- 
library/2.12.7/scala-library-2.12.7.pom.sha1
Downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom
Downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala- 
parser-combinators_2.12/1.1.1/scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.1.1.pom
Downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.12/2.2.6/scalatest_2.12-2.2.6.pom.sha1
Downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.7/scala-ibrary-2.12.7.pom

[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:ssExtractDependencies for the 
full output. [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last 
*:coursierSbtClassifiersResolution for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last :coursierResolutions for the full 
output.
[error] (:ssExtractDependencies) coursier.ResolutionException: Exception 
during resolution
[error] (:coursierSbtClassifiersResolution) coursier.ResolutionException: 
Exception during resolution
[error] (:coursierResolutions) coursier.ResolutionException: Exception 
during resolution
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 2018.10.22. 13:08:00
```

build.sbt content:

```
name := course.value + "-" + assignment.value

scalaVersion := "2.12.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest_2.11" % "3.0.5" % 
"test"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation")

// grading libraries libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % 
Test

// for funsets libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala- 
parser-combinators" % "1.1.1"

// include the common dir commonSourcePackages += "common"

courseId := "bRPXgjY9EeW6RApRXdjJPw"
```

Comment: can you link the exact project you are having trouble with? Also, does it help if you move the project to some directory outside your user directory? Potentially the encoding of the characters in your user name are causing the issue.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the hint! It has solved the problem. I have modified the name of the user folder and now the project works as it was intended. I should have thought about the special characters...